# Unexpected behaviour during UnitOfWork

Tags: messaging, unit-of-work, rebus

Any messages send/publish inside a message handler will be dispatched when the transaction is committed. (This is a really nice OOTB behaviour)

I have implemented [UnitOfWork](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/UnitOfWork) per your example. Discovered that if a exception occurred inside the action of `OnCommitted(action)` the enqueued messages might get sent, it just depends if the [deliver task](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/c35182188929f4ee38305b8654068a57b4172ea1/Rebus/Transport/InMem/InMemTransport.cs#L53) is executed before the `uow.commit()` action.

I have found a work around by adding a process step that at the end of the receive pipeline. It checks if a uow exists in the current context and then commits the uow. If a exception like a *database schema change* occurs during the commit it happens before OnCommitted is called and non of the enqueued messages is dispatched.

What is the correct way to implement a UnitOfWork with Rebus?

Comment: thanks for making me realize that this is something I need to address - I'll provide a solution soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the [Rebus.UnitOfWork](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.UnitOfWork/) package and see if you can use it?

It provides a redesigned unit of work API for Rebus that allows you to go:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => {
        o.EnableUnitOfWork(Create, Commit);
    })
```

where `Create` and `Commit` could be like this:

```
public YourOwnUnitOfWork Create(IMessageContext context)
{
    return new YourOwnUnitOfWork(...);
}

public void Commit(IMessageContext context, YourOwnUnitOfWork uow)
{
    uow.Commit();
}
```